# Image not found for displaying in servlet using img tag

Tags: java, servlets

I have a webpage (htm) that has a textbox (going to change it to a drop-down selection).

I write there a name of picture (.png, .jpg, .gif) and hit a submit button

A servlet is invoked and i am trying to display an image having that name which the user had typed in webpage.

The images are present in the same directory as the .class files of servlet are present, 
but when I try to display it using the `<img>` tag (by writing it to PrintWriter's stream) from servlet, I get resource not available.

I manually also tried to locate the few images using `localhost:8080/webAppName/imgName` but still resource isn't found.

I get false also when i try to use `exists()` method of `File` class.

The servlet works fine, I have displayed a some text as a response to client but its unable to locate the image.

Servlet is invoked as HTTP GET.

Here is the servlet code:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Expt16_3PassImg2Servlet extends HttpServlet
{
    String IPMsg;
    String imgName="";

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
    imgName=request.getParameter("imgNameEntry");
    boolean imgExists=true;
    pw.println("<html>");
    pw.println("<body>");
    //if((new File("./"+imgName)).exists())
        pw.println("<img src=\""+imgName+"\">");
    //else
        //pw.println("<h1>Image doesnt exist</h1>");
    pw.println("</body>");
    pw.println("</html>");
    pw.println("<br>Sample Text");

}
}
```

I know we can display a image by setting content type as image/jpeg but i want to display it using the img tag.

And by the way as you would have seen, I am extending my servlet to HttpServlet.

Comment: Please note that your servlet is not threadsafe.

Comment: Hmm thanks for that..but thats just a sample dummy code..
it isnt the actual one..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image should be in the web directory--the same place you put any other publicly-accessible resource, like an HTML file (but not under `WEB-INF`).

The client has zero clue about classpath resources. Unless you map an image name to a classpath resources and stream back the bytes, images on the classpath are invisible to the client.

---

How will a user know what the name of an image is?

Comment: Hmm actually going to have a drop down selection having names..names are going to tell about the images itself..

Comment: and hey thanks..such a small silly mistake..!
Actually new to JAVA servlets..i think started like day before yesterday....THANKS!

Comment: If @Daves response satisfies you, please reward him and mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your web app name or context name is 'MyWebApp' Your images directory would be like MyWebApp/allimages

then here is how your image tag look like

img src='MyWebApp/allimages/imagename.png' id='' alt=''